# What type of file Can i open with os.system or os.startfile?

Tags: python, operating-system

What type of file Can i open with `os.system` or `os.startfile`?
I know you can use:

```
paths,
file.txt,
file.py,
file.js,
file.css,
```

etc..

but how do you open Chrome and other applications

Comment: `os.system()` simply executes the command that you give it. Anything you can type to the command prompt window should work.

Comment: For `os.startfile()` I think you would have to give it the path to a web shortcut for it to open the browser.

Answer (score 0):

Python os.startfile is a very useful command. You can not only open files but also applications. One way is to click on an application and copy path. Then put in that path into os.startfile(). Remember it has to be an exe or lnk file.
Here's and example:

```
os.startfile('Chrome.exe')
```

When you write this code, python will open Chrome for you.
To open links though in chrome you can use the webbrowser module in such a way:

```
webbrowser.open_new_tab('https://web.whatsapp.com/')
```

Thank You! I hope this was useful for you!